# How to create listener for spring session destroyed events?

Tags: spring-session

I have a code as below:

```
@Component
public class LogoutListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent>
{
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event)
  {
    System.out.println("Application event happened");
    for (SecurityContext securityContext : event.getSecurityContexts())
    {
        System.out.println("session has ended");   
    }
  }
}
```

Since I am using a spring boot app.I cant use web.xml.Then how can I configure the listener.
This listener is looking for session destroyed events.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752556/3857549) might be helpful. In it you'll find that, for applications without web.xml, you have to look at ServletContext.html#addListener

Comment: helpfool, yes. Please write your questions so that they would even be of value if the linnks you refer to are dead.

Comment: Agreed. You have to include the information in the question itself. Once the link expires your question will be useless.

Comment: @Clijsters, L. Guthardt: when you say _questions_ do you mean _answer_? 
So what you say is that I should include the whole info from the referenced link, right?
Sorry, as you might notice this is my first contribution.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant answers. Ok, did you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) like it was suggested as you created your account? There are some helpful articles like [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
public class SessionEventListener extends HttpSessionEventPublisher {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        super.sessionCreated(event);
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60*3);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        String name = null;
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = getSessionRegistry(event);
        SessionInformation sessionInfo = (sessionRegistry != null ? sessionRegistry
            .getSessionInformation(event.getSession().getId()) : null);
        UserDetails ud = null;
        if (sessionInfo != null) {
            ud = (UserDetails) sessionInfo.getPrincipal();}
        if (ud != null) {
            name = ud.getUsername();
            // YOUR METHOD IS CALLED HERE 
            getMyService(event).myMethod(name);
        }
        super.sessionDestroyed(event);
    }

    public YourBean4Service getMyService(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        ApplicationContext ctx =
            WebApplicationContextUtils.
                    getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());
        return (YourBean4Service) ctx.getBean("yourBean4Service");
    }

    public SessionRegistry getSessionRegistry(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        ApplicationContext ctx =
            WebApplicationContextUtils.
                    getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());
        return (SessionRegistry) ctx.getBean("sessionRegistry");
    }
}
```

And my related topic is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101252/session-isnt-destroyed-just-after-being-expired-manually-in-spring-security)